# What third-party frameworks / libraries / utilities exist to aid the creation of forms with UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I've spent the past few days making a nice form using a UITableView. This includes shuttling values back and forth to entities managed by Core Data (they are laid out arbitrarily which makes using NSFetchedResultsController impractical), adding nested UITableViews for choosing between multiple values, validating the data and displaying errors when values are invalid, adding support for "tabbing" between fields using the return button, and so forth.

Bravo to Cocoa Touch for bringing so much to the table, but there's still lots and lots of glue code I wrote that could be abstracted out. It would be fun to do this, but I can't believe that ~2 years into iOS development there aren't already lots of open-source projects that provide helper solutions to this.

I've looked at dozens of iOS-related open-source projects, but I haven't found anything related to this area beyond a few custom cells here and there.

Can you point me to any projects that ideally provide holistic solutions to this? I'm also interested in the "point solution" frameworks if you know of any.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IBAForms](https://github.com/ittybittydude/IBAForms#readme) looks quite promising and supports binding the form to a model using KVC.

Comment: That does indeed look promising, thanks for the link!